# How to Delete Multiple Rows in Power Apps Data Table

Tags: canvas, datatable, powerapps, delete-row, sharepoint-list

I have a Power Apps Data table and this data table retrieves my SharePoint list [Vacation Budget] records. I have already removed multiple records in the data table using the RemoveIf function based on the SharePoint list choice field value. But, my requirement is how to delete the last two rows or the middle of three rows in the Power Apps data table.
Code is: [image] `RemoveIf( 'Vacation Budget', Category.Value = "Entertainment" )`

Please suggest any code for this requirement...

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question. "I have already removed multiple records in the data table using the RemoveIf " - so what is the problem/issue? "my requirement is how to delete the last two rows or the middle of three rows in the Power Apps data table" - why these rows, what's the logic for these row selections?

Comment: My question is if I want to remove FirstN or LastN rows in the Data table, it's possible or not?

Comment: Look at using `Remove` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-remove-removeif